# HTML required input field bubble off position (Google Chrome)?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

**Edit:**
I set up a clean fiddle with minimum of HTML and **no** CSS:

```
<form>
<input type="text" required />
<input type="submit" required />
</form>
```

Result:

[image]

Link:
https://jsfiddle.net/d1d9g7sw/

This result is reflected in my own test template, and I want that required message bubble aligned left. Looks like, this is only happening on Google Chrome. My current version (up to date): *Version 59.0.3071.115 (Offizieller Build) (64-Bit)*

Comment: Please share your HTML code, so we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: Works fine with the code you provided. Can you also give us your complete CSS code? https://jsfiddle.net/dtgdoz7g/

Comment: @KamalChhirang when I submit in your fiddle, the bubble is centered, same problem :/ - chrome is up to date

Answer (score 0):

Its default alert box of the browser and you cannot position that. Instead you can use custom alert box and position according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot style browsers generic validation tooltips. There is a good reason for it, and Chrome devs resigned from ::-webkit-validation-bubble pseudoelement.

What I could suggest is to use alternative JS validator and style your own tooltips as you please.

My hint would be [parsley.js](http://parsleyjs.org/) lib